# get the first entry in an entity on Core Data

Tags: xcode, core-data, entity

I was wondering how to get the first item from an entity in core data without using fetch?

Reason i asked is because i placed the settings file onto core data instead of creating a separate file to hold the values. Because when ever the app is updated, the separate file gets blown off and core data is migrated. if i placed the user's settings onto a file, it is not preserved when the app is updated. Core data is preserved (give or take some hoops).

I know how to fetch but is there any other way (easier way) to just get the 1st entry on the core data entity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am afraid you have to go through the motions of fetching. You can make it very efficient by setting the `fetchLimit` to `1`. With the available convenience methods it is really very short, both in Swift and Objective-C.

```
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Event")
request.fetchLimit = 1
let result = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error:nil) as [Event]
if countElements(result) == 1 {
   let event = result.first! as Event
   // do something with event
}
```

or

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Event"];
request.fetchLimit = 1;
NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
if (result.count) {
    Event *event = result.firstObject;
    // do something with event
}
```

Comment: hummm!! Thank you for your feedback :) I'll use this instead :) Reason why i asked is because i know that the settings entity will always have 1 entry only. one thing that I've thought is just fetching the "User face picture" since it will always never be nil and will definitely return 1 object ;)

Comment: Actually, if it is *always* one entry, a simple plist will probably be much better. You can persist the contents of a plist (or of user defaults) via iCloud across app installations and versions.